# collision while using sprite sheet in corona

Tags: coronasdk

how can i create collision between the objects added to physics body and sprite sheet...
as i dont want to add my sprite sheet in physics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a blank rect to map the position of your sprite and handle collisons based on that